# Changing BroadcastReceiver to existing users

Tags: java, android

When we make changes to a BroadcastReceiver and update the app on the Play Store, what happens to users who already had that BroadcastReceiver scheduled from an AlarmManager? Does it get canceled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, alarms are managed at the OS-level so reinstalling your app does not interrupt them. Otherwise, your app would be dead until it could receive some other arbitrary broadcast like boot complete.